# Acumatica no UNION JOIN for Report Designer, have any way to get this result?

Tags: sql-server, acumatica

I want to create the report for Kit Specification Inventory, but while I creating I see the tables that store about Stock and Non-stock are not in one table. In the report I want to use the sort of type inventory. As my picture below:

1. The result I need and wrong result i'm doing now
2. Tables joining
3. Report result
4. Report layout

This is what I use UNION

```
SELECT a.CompanyID,a.KitInventoryID,a.RevisionID,a.CompInventoryID,a.DfltCompQty,a.UOM,a.MinCompQty,a.MaxCompQty,d.InventoryCD,d.Descr
      FROM dbo.INKitSpecStkDet a
           INNER JOIN dbo.InventoryItem d ON a.CompInventoryID=d.InventoryID
 UNION All
 SELECT b.CompanyID,b.KitInventoryID,b.RevisionID,b.CompInventoryID,b.DfltCompQty,b.UOM,b.MinCompQty,b.MaxCompQty,c.InventoryCD,c.Descr 
      FROM dbo.INKitSpecNonStkDet b
           INNER JOIN dbo.InventoryItem c ON b.KitInventoryID=c.InventoryID
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you explain a bit more, you want table A records and then table B records ?

Comment: As picture 1, I want to get the rows of table A and B combine together so if table A has 3 rows, table B has 1 row and the result I want is 4 rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this is what you want.

```
create table #TableA
(
ID varchar(10),
Name varchar(20),
Type varchar(10),
Value int
)

create table #TableB
(
ID varchar(10),
Name varchar(20),
Type varchar(10),
Value int
)
insert into #TableA values ('0001','ItemA','A',100)
insert into #TableA values ('0002','ItemB','A',100)
insert into #TableA values ('0003','ItemC','A',100)

insert into #TableB values ('0001','ItemA','B',100)
insert into #TableB values ('0002','ItemB','B',100)
insert into #TableB values ('0003','ItemC','B',100)
insert into #TableB values ('0004','ItemD','B',100)
insert into #TableB values ('0005','ItemE','B',100)

select * from #TableA
union
select * from #TableB where name not in(select Name from #TableA)
```

See if this Helps

```
SELECT COALESCE(#TableA.ID, #TableB.ID) AS ID, 
COALESCE(#TableA.Name, #TableB.Name)AS Name,COALESCE(#TableA.Type, #TableB.Type)AS Type,COALESCE(#TableA.Value, #TableB.Value)AS Value
FROM #TableA
FULL OUTER JOIN #TableB
ON #TableB.ID = #TableA.ID
```

Comment: Yes, it works! But in report I can't use union select. So do I need to create view or anything else?

Comment: Yes you can create a view or Stored Procedure according to you requirement.

Comment: So join can't do what I want? I mean if I just only use join can I get the result I want?

Comment: Not sure about unit joins in Acuamtica. You could try to create a view in SQL and create a DAC for this view in Acumatica and then use it for your report. This however would not be reasonable for a certified Customization in Acumatica.

Comment: Yes, that's the way I'm doing now. I just want to make sure but anyways thank u so much.